# Windows client for GNU Screen

Tags: windows, gnu-screen, putty

I'm very happy with Putty running on my Windows machine and keeping all my terminal windows under GNU Screen in my server. However, I wonder if there's a version of Putty (or another software for that matter) that is Screen-aware and which lets me to organize and browse my windows opened under a Screen session. Maybe keeping every window in a separate Windows window, features for easy browsing between the windows, etc...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch several putty instances, and attach each one of them to the same screen instance (use the -x option). Then, within screen, create multiple windows; you will be able to switch to any of them from any of the open terminals ! this way you can have one terminal per virtual screen, or keep some others in the back, etc..